# How to rescue usb stick / probability of recovery

Tags: mac, usb, data-recovery

My partner is mourning over a broken usb stick and hopes to get some of the data back. What happened was that the usb was plugged into the MacBook, the cover was shut and the battery drained fully after a while.

The problem is that the usb stick doesn't seem to register at all when plugging it into a Mac or Linux machine (also nothing in the logs when connecting it). I find this quite puzzling and think that this might point to some physical damage but wouldn't know how a draining battery could have done that...

Are there any ways to recover some of the data? Could specialists be able to recover it? Would it be worthwhile to open it and see if there is some damage? (I haven't opened it since some specialist firms seem to charge more if you have tried to open the stick yourself)

The usb stick is a SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 64GB

**Edit**

I ran`journalctl -f` and plugged the usb in.... no reaction unfortunately... :(
Could the damage (in theory) be something that could be fixed easily (e.g. fixing some connections) or is it definitely some high end lab type activity?

Comment: The damage could be a broken track/connection which  might be salvageable with a usb cable and soldering iron - ofcourse this could make things worse as well.

Comment: Thinking about possible causes (didnt find it - I was thinking about heat/cooling from batery and solder reflow ) did lead me to http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/Other-Cruzer-USB-Flash-drives/Can-USB-connector-be-repaired-on-a-Cruzer-flash-drive/td-p/196745 which would seem very  much on point.

Comment: @davidgo thanks a lot for the link, this looks really good. At least I got something to start talking about now when calling some specialist (or even a how-to in case I decide / am forced to do my own soldering....)

Answer (score 1):

If its truly not recogniseable when plugged in, specialists may be able to recover it, but it won't come cheap (Not something your local camera or It store can help you with).  It most likely involves desoldering the memory sticks and doing forensics.

If, on the other hand the USB drive is being recognised, but its not finding the filesystem, you have a good chance of partial or full recovery using Testdisk and/or Photorec.   To check if this is a possibility, boot a Linux system, then open a terminal window and type

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages  (this might be /var/log/syslog on some distros)
```

Then see what, if anything it reports when you plug the stick in.  If it talks about /dev/sdX then you may be in luck and Photorec and/or Testdisk can probably save the day - otherwise amend what it says to your question, leave a comment to say you have done so and I, or someone else can look at it and comment on your chances - but they won't be high !

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I edited my question :( doesn't sound good though...